# how to pass a runtime parameter from html code to javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

the point was to get focus on a particular element of a webpage on mouse move by changing the background color of the element.

The html is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<base src="..... />
<script>....</script>
<link..../>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold"> Enter values or choose options 
in the form below .</p>
<div id="d1">

<form id="f1" action="" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend><a name="pdet"></a>Personal Details</legend>
    <table id="t1" width="400" height="auto" rows="4" cols="2">
        <tr id="tr1" onMouseMove ="focus(tr1)" onMouseOut ="original(tr1)">
            <td><label for="fname">First Name :<label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname" col="30"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2" onMouseMove ="focus(tr2)" onMouseOut ="original(tr2)">
            <td><label for="lname">Last Name : </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="lname" col="30"></input></td>                
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript functions are as follows

```
function focus(e_id){
var element = document.getElementById("e_id").style.backgroundColor ="blue";
}

function original(e_id){
var element = document.getElementById("e_id").style.backgroundColor="green";
}
```

Read the previous ans on the same topic where it was suggested to do so by using 'focus(this)' or 'focus(this.id)' as arguments to pass the element itself or the id of the element respectively. Tried it but it did not work.

can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: "e_id" is a string, not a reference to the variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's just a problem with incorrect usage of quotes.

```js
function elfocus(e_id){
// do not use quotes around e_id in order to use the function argument
var element = document.getElementById(e_id).style.backgroundColor ="blue";
}

function original(e_id){
var element = document.getElementById(e_id).style.backgroundColor="green";
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold"> Enter values or choose options 
in the form below .</p>
<div id="d1">

<form id="f1" action="" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend><a name="pdet"></a>Personal Details</legend>
    <table id="t1" width="400" height="auto" rows="4" cols="2">
        <tr id="tr1" onMouseMove ="elfocus('tr1')" onMouseOut ="original('tr1')">
        <!-- put single quotes arount tr1 so that it is passed as a string -->
            <td><label for="fname">First Name :<label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="fname" col="30"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr2" onMouseMove ="elfocus('tr2')" onMouseOut ="original('tr2')">
            <td><label for="lname">Last Name : </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="lname" col="30"></input></td>                
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<br/>
```

Also I renamed the focus function, because `window.focus` is an existing function already so the event listeners might not use your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your main issue might be that you're using `"e_id"` (a string) rather than `e_id` (a variable identifier).